# EmberJS Application... can integrate with UI Frameworks?

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, ember.js

This is probably a subjective question, so I will try to structure it in an acceptable way.

I am developing an app using emberJS for the first time.  So far, I like what ember can do, however I have learned it is still a little bit lacking in the UI department.

To avoid re-inventing any wheels, I am considering using some css gris and jquery libs or perhaps a full-fledged UI framework that includes all the date-picking, carousel, table-sorting, etc. that I might need.

I have looked into bootstrap, kendo ui, and jquery ui as possible candidates, but I am getting the feeling that I am going to be just loading conflicting frameworks that might net me a few boons, but ultimately end up creating a bloat of wasted code.

My question is:  Is there a layout/UI framework that has been known to work well (e.g. compliment) ember? or am I better off just using a few stand alone libraries that will suit specific needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Ember with Bootstrap + FlatUI free theme. I'm doing the integration manually. There are also libraries that will do it for you (like [this](https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember) one). The very fact that they exists should give you a clue as to the ease of integration - it's possible, but not automatic and sometimes not easy.

The simplest cases are trivial, but if you want bootstrap widgets to respond to Ember changes (eg. change tooltip based on data), you'll have to do some custom coding. I would either create a View wrapping single bootstrap widget, or create a view mixin I can attach to page views. I didn't dig too deep, but I suspect Bootstrap for Ember is doing similar things.

Is it worth it? For bootstrap or jQueryUI, I would say yes. These libraries have minimal coding and are really more oriented towards presentation. Their widgets are a good candidates for encapsulation in Ember's views and components. KendoUI, I'm less familiar with. But as long as a library keeps its javascript contained and pattern-agnostic, I'd say give it a shot.

Comment: I looked into Ember for Bootstrap and I liked it.  I think I can use a lot of these components as a starting point.  Thanks!  I also liked "Ember UI" but it looks like is is still a work in progress with no real release yet.